# Erro na hora de iniciar a "Homestead" no Vagrant

Tags: laravel, homestead

diogo.barbosa@Mysterio MINGW64 /c/ambiente_dev/maquinas_virtuais/vagrant_boxes/Homestead (release)

$ vagrant up

C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 20 column 10 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in`parse_stream'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in`load'
        from C:/ambiente_dev/maquinas_virtuais/vagrant_boxes/Homestead/Vagrantfile:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in`each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in`each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:29:in`initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in`vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:973:in `process_configured_plugins'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in`initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/bin/vagrant:145:in`'

Answer (score 0):

No caso descobri que no meu arquivo "**Homestead.yaml**" haviam espaços a "**mais**" em algumas partes o que ocasionava erros.

Assim que removi os espaços extras no arquivo "**Homestead.yaml**" pude acessar a máquina o problema de arquivos com extensão "**.yaml**" é que são sensíveis a espaços extras.